# Unable to connect to libvirt qemu://system

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am trying to setup a GPU passthrough for KVM but I've been facing this egregious problem the whole time. Basically, it's telling me to verify whether libvirt is running or not.

```
Unable to connect to libvirt qemu:///system.
Verify that the 'libvirtd' daemon is running.
Libvirt URI is: qemu:///system
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 922, in _do_open
    self._backend.open(cb, data)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/connection.py", line 153, in open
    conn = libvirt.openAuth(self._open_uri,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 148, in openAuth
    raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Connection refused
```

When I check the status of libvirt, it indeed isn't active. But I couldn't myself a solution.

```
*aleeq@aleeq-MS-7A15:~$ sudo systemctl status libvirtd
[sudo] password for aleeq: 
× libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor pres>
     Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Wed 2022-03-02 21:27:26 +08>
TriggeredBy: × libvirtd-ro.socket
             × libvirtd.socket
             × libvirtd-admin.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
    Process: 2948 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $libvirtd_opts (code=exited, sta>
   Main PID: 2948 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 32768)
     Memory: 9.7M
        CPU: 168ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
             ├─1198 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/defa>
             └─1199 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/defa>
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 dnsmasq[1198]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/defa>
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 dnsmasq-dhcp[1198]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq>
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Deactivated success>
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 1198 (>
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 1199 (>
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Start request repea>
lines 1-23...skipping...
× libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Wed 2022-03-02 21:27:26 +08; 5min ago
TriggeredBy: × libvirtd-ro.socket
             × libvirtd.socket
             × libvirtd-admin.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
    Process: 2948 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $libvirtd_opts (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2948 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 32768)
     Memory: 9.7M
        CPU: 168ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
             ├─1198 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
             └─1199 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 dnsmasq[1198]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts - 0 addresses
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 dnsmasq-dhcp[1198]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.hostsfile
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 1198 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 1199 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 1198 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 1199 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 1-27/27 (END)
× libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Wed 2022-03-02 21:27:26 +08; 5min ago
TriggeredBy: × libvirtd-ro.socket
             × libvirtd.socket
             × libvirtd-admin.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
    Process: 2948 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $libvirtd_opts (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2948 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 32768)
     Memory: 9.7M
        CPU: 168ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
             ├─1198 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leases>
             └─1199 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leases>
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 dnsmasq[1198]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts - 0 addresses
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 dnsmasq-dhcp[1198]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.hostsfile
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 1198 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 1199 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 1198 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 1199 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Mac 02 21:27:26 aleeq-MS-7A15 systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 1-27/27 (END)*
```

I'm looking forward for a solution. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please try following `sudo systemctl stop apparmor.service` then try again.

Comment: As you already found your problem seem to be that libvirt doesn't start up properly. Therefore the question is what exactly happens. You can run `journalctl -xe -u libvirtd` and hopefully see the problem right away.
Let us know what the problem was or report the non ellipsized output here for a better chance of help.